# Прокрутка текстового поля при добавлении текста

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Как "прикрутить" автоматическую прокрутку полоски по мере появления текста, то есть чтоб полоска шла вниз как только текст появляется?

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading

def start_tk():
        root = Tk()
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
        scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )

        mylist = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
        mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
        scrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview )

        def insert_in_widget():
                for line in range(100):
                   time.sleep(0.1)
                   mylist.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))

        insert_in_widget_thread = threading.Thread(target=insert_in_widget)
        insert_in_widget_thread.start()


        mainloop()



start = threading.Thread(target=start_tk)

start.start()
```

Comment: Господа , неужели никто не может помочь?

Comment: После `mylist.insert(...)` делайте `mylist.yview(END)`

Answer (score 0):

После вставки текста делайте `mylist.yview(END)` или `mylist.yview_moveto(1.0)`, тогда будет прокручиваться в самый низ текстового поля:

```
def insert_in_widget():
    for line in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        mylist.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))
        mylist.yview(END)
        # или mylist.yview_moveto(1.0)
```

Вообще, не стоит оборачивать основной код tkinter в отдельный поток, выполняйте в отдельном потоке только блокирующий цикл:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading


root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )

mylist = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
scrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview )

def insert_in_widget():
    for line in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        mylist.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))
        mylist.yview(END)

insert_in_widget_thread = threading.Thread(target=insert_in_widget)
insert_in_widget_thread.start()

mainloop()
```